# Multiple UIWebViews, how do I track webViewDidFinishLoad for both?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I've tried:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{

}
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView2{

}
```

Errors are that I can't redefine the same method.

If I have to use the same method, I need to figure out some way of identifying one webView from the other, how would I do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{
     if ( webview == self.webview1 )
     {
          // in case of webview 1
     } else if ( webview == self.webview2 ) {
          // in case of webview 2
     } else {
          NSLog(@"webview %@ was not wired to a property of %@",webview,self);
     }
}
```

and add webview1 and webview2 as properties to your controller. (i.e. you need the @property line and a @synthesize line)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` passes a webview is so that you know which webview finished loading. You have a couple of options.

1. Create class variables for webview1 and webview2 and the compare it with webview.
2. Tag the webviews so you know which one

**1.**

```
//SomeController.h
@interface SomeController : UIViewController
    UIWebView *webView1;
    UIWebView *webView2;
@end

//SomeController.m
...
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if(webView == webView1) { ... }
    else if(webView == webView2) { ... }
}
...
```

**2.**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView1.tag = 1;
    webView2.tag = 2;
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if(webView.tag == 1) { ... }
    else if(webView.tag == 2) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to them when you create them programmatically OR add outlets for them from Interface Builder. That way you'll have instance variables you can compare to the `webView` method argument to see which one has finished loading. You only need one method for this, and you may want to [read up on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   if (webView == webView1)
   {
      // handle webView1's loading
   }
   else if (webView == webView2)
   {
      // handle webView2's loading
   }
}
```