# iOS increase UIWebView font size

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I looked for solution on Stack Overflow but I didn't find one. My code is:

```
CGRect  rect = _postContentView.bounds;
_postContentUIWV = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[_postContentUIWV loadHTMLString:selectedPostCD.content baseURL:nil];

int fontSize = 30;
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
    @"document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='%d%%'",
    fontSize];
[_postContentUIWV stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

[_postContentView addSubview:_postContentUIWV];
```

And the part of HTML inside `UIWebView`:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    <span style="line-height: 1.5em;">blablablablablabla</span>
</p>
```

My code doesn't increase the font size inside `UIWebView`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Where have you put your code? is it in the `webViewDidFinishLoad ` UIWebView delegate method ?

Comment: It is in - (void)viewDidLoad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the code related to creation and initialization of `_postContentUIWV` inside the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect  rect = _postContentView.bounds;
    _postContentUIWV = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    _postContentUIWV.delegate = self;
    [_postContentUIWV loadHTMLString:selectedPostCD.content baseURL:nil];
    [_postContentView addSubview:_postContentUIWV];
}
```

Move the code related to evaluation of `jsString` to the `webViewDidFinishLoad` method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    int fontSize = 30;
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
        @"document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='%d%%'",
        fontSize];
    [_postContentUIWV stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, you are my lifesaver

Comment: Lots of info on how to adjust web text size-  but I needed this for saving and restoring the user's preference!  If you have multiple webviews like me- see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553610/multiple-uiwebviews-how-do-i-track-webviewdidfinishload-for-both

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, you can concatenate string to existing HTML inside `UIWebView`:

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<style>p {font-size:28px}</style>";
makeBiggerCssString = [makeBiggerCssString stringByAppendingString:
                       selectedPostCD.content];
[_postContentUIWV loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
NSString *htmlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<font face='Font_name' size='30'>%@", Yourstring];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```